# What are the definitions for LPARAM and WPARAM?

Tags: c#, c++, windows

I know I'm being lazy here and I should trawl the header files for myself, but what are the actual types for LPARAM and WPARAM parameters? Are they pointers, or four byte ints? I'm doing some C# interop code and want to be sure I get it working on x64 systems.

Comment: You could just right-click on `LAPARAM` and select 'Go to declaration'...

Comment: @John - I could if I had a Visual C++ IDE, but I'm doing C# dev. Finding the actual definitions of these things is annoyingly time consuming if you're not working with a C++ IDE. I just had to manually follow a trail of several typedefs to find out what was at the end of HACMDRIVERID. If the MSDN documentation was properly hyperlinked it would have saved me a lot of bother.

Comment: @Mark: Then why is this question marked C++?

Comment: @Mark: Or why not just create a C++ project, type in "LPARAM" and right click there?

Comment: @John - because its the C++ guys who know that stuff off the top of their heads. I know I did 8 years ago, but I've been living in a managed world for a long time now! But good point, I should probably make myself a C++ project just for this purpose.

Comment: Might be a lazy question... On the other hand it's the top answer at google when searching for wparam, so your not the only one that want a fast answer, and now everyone gets just that!

Comment: @JohnDibling what if you work with MASM32??!?!is there any `just right-click on LAPARAM and select 'Go to declaration'`

Comment: @JesonPark: This question is tagged c#.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

`LPARAM` is a typedef for `LONG_PTR` which is a `long` (signed 32-bit) on win32 and `__int64` (signed 64-bit) on x86_64.

`WPARAM` is a typedef for `UINT_PTR` which is an `unsigned int` (unsigned 32-bit) on win32 and `unsigned __int64` (unsigned 64-bit) on x86_64.

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @Charles Bailey: maybe I'm misunderstanding you but when you say: "__int64 (signed 64-bit) on x86" don't you mean "on x86-64" or win64 or something? I take x86 to be 32-bit.

Comment: @User: Yes, it's supposed to say x86_64 which is how Microsoft now refer to amd64.

Comment: Please notice that the description refers to `long` in C++. In C#, a `long` is a signed 64bit, also when compiling to 32bit.

Answer (score 72):

These typedefs go back to the 16-bit days.  Originally, `LPARAM` was a `long` (signed 32-bit) and `WPARAM` was a `WORD` (unsigned 16-bit), hence the [W and L](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031125-00/?p=41713).  Due to the common practice of passing casted pointers as message parameters, `WPARAM` was expanded to 32 bits on Win32, and both `LPARAM` and `WPARAM` were expanded to 64 bits on Win64.

In C#, you should use `IntPtr` for `LPARAM` and `UIntPtr` for WPARAM.

Note that despite the `LP` prefix, `LPARAM` is not a far pointer to an `ARAM`.

Comment: Note that the term "word" in the field of computer means a data size a CPU can process at a time (such as the size of the register) and it's related to the bus size. OTOH, `WORD` is Microsoft term, and it was the same size as "word" in the 16-bit days, but now their sizes are different. `DWORD`(32bit), and `QWORD`(64bit) have fixed sizes, too. From Wikipedia: *"Microsoft's Windows API maintains the programming language definition of WORD as 16 bits, despite the fact that the API may be used on a 32- or 64-bit x86 processor, where the standard word size would be 32 or 64 bits, respectively."*

Comment: `WPARAM` is 32-bit because handles in Win32 are 32-bit pointers, where they used to be 16-bit selectors. In 16-bit Windows, passing pointers was done via `LPARAM`. It didn't become significantly more prevalent in Win32, because it was already quite common.

Answer (score 6):

LPARAM refers to a LONG_PTR and WPARAM refers to a UINT_PTR

On x86 they will be 4 bytes and on x64 they will be 8 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

[Here:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751(VS.85).aspx)

```
typedef UINT_PTR WPARAM;
typedef LONG_PTR LPARAM;
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need my friend is http://www.pinvoke.net/

Comment: yes, its a useful site, although very mixed quality interop conversions

Answer (score 0):

c++ in linux and windows 64bit tested, the most simple solution I found:

```
#define WPARAM long long unsigned int
#define LPARAM long long int
```