# error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'long' to 'LRESULT'

Tags: visual-c++

I am converting my project from a 32 bit version to 64 bit version, when compiling the project in 64 bit, i get the below error.

```
Error   2   error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'long (__cdecl BrnDefDlgClass::* )(UINT,long)' to 'LRESULT (__cdecl CWnd::* )(WPARAM,LPARAM)'  C:\Program Files (x86)\...\CXX\TEST.CXX 854 1   cfg
```

this error points me to below line of code.

```
ON_MESSAGE        (WM_USER_AFTERCBNSELCHANGE,   OnAfterCBSelectMsg)
```

advice please why would this error occur.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the part of the  code

Comment: error occurs in the code i have posted above in second block

Comment: how does the signature of `OnAfterCBSelectMsg` look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you look at the definition of `OnAfterCBSelectMsg` and modify it to use `LRESULT` as return type, and `WPARAM` and `LPARAM` as parameters (just as the second signature in your error message).

`LRESULT` is defined as `LONG_PTR`, and whenever `PTR` appears in a name, you should expect it to be large enough to hold a pointer. Pointers are 4 bytes on 32 Bit and 8 bytes on 64 bit, so an `LRESULT` won't fit into a `long` (which is 4 bytes) if you compile for 64 bit.

Using `WPARAM` and `LPARAM` as parameter types is also important, as their size changes depending on the platform, too. See the answers to this question for more info:  [What are the definitions for LPARAM and WPARAM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2515261/93652)

Answer (score 2):

`WPARAM` is defined as `unsigned __int64`, `LRESULT` and `LPARAM` are `__int64` in 64-bit Windows.

You have to change the signature of `BrnDefDlgClass` accordingly. If the WinAPI-provided typedefs were used instead of built-in types, it would be compilable on both 32 and 64-bit platforms.