# Mapping platform specific interoperable types

Tags: c#, c++, .net, interop, pinvoke

The [Windows Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reference lists the following types:

```
#if defined(_WIN64) 
 typedef __int64 INT_PTR; 
#else 
 typedef int INT_PTR;
#endif

#if defined(_WIN64)
 typedef __int64 LONG_PTR; 
#else
 typedef long LONG_PTR;
#endif
```

Since .NET (mostly) does away with preprocessor directives it's not easy to map these exactly. I can see two options, and I would like to know which is best:

**Use IntPtr because it's platform specific**

```
using INT_PTR = System.IntPtr;
using LONG_PTR = System.IntPtr;
```

**Use the bigger size integer, just in case we're running on x64**

```
using INT_PTR = System.Int64;
using LONG_PTR = System.Int64;
```

My gut feeling is to use `IntPtr` over `Int64`, however I would like some insight as to what really is the best option.

**Remarks**

**Question:** What problem are you trying to solve?

**Answer:** Generally mapping windows data types to .NET, as closely as possible to support future PInvoke operations.

**Question:** How PInvoke is related to this question?

**Answer:** The windows data types are required for correctly mapping managed data into PInvoke/d (unmanaged) signatures (future use)

**Example:**

**Native Declaration:**

```
LRESULT WINAPI SendMessage(
  _In_  HWND hWnd,
  _In_  UINT Msg,
  _In_  WPARAM wParam,
  _In_  LPARAM lParam
);
```

**PInvoke Declaration variations:**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(
    [In] IntPtr hWnd,
    [In] uint Msg,
    [In] UIntPtr wParam,
    [In] IntPtr lParam
);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
public static extern long SendMessage(
    [In] IntPtr hWnd,
    [In] uint Msg,
    [In] ulong wParam,
    [In] long lParam
);
```

In the example above, the first instance uses IntPtr and UIntPtr (platform specific) types, whereas the second uses long and ulong, "just in case" running on x64

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? How PInvoke is related to this question?

Comment: @AlexFarber - see remarks

Comment: Agiin, it is not clear. `IntPtr` has correct size for 32 and 64 bit. Native Dll called by PInvoke has the same bitness, so IntPtr has the same size as void*

Comment: @AlexFarber therefore say I want to PInvoke something that uses INT_PTR; is the use implementation specific (I need to pick the correct .NET data type according to the implementation rather than using IntPtr vs Int32/Int64 generally)?

Comment: You cannot PInvoke 32 bit Dll from 64 bit process, and 64 bit Dll from 32 bit process. So, if you PInvoke native Dll with parameter INT_PTR, declare it as IntPtr, the size of both will be the same.

Comment: @AlexFarber - I've added an example to illustrate what I mean

Comment: First declaration is correct both for 32 abd 64 bit. Second probably causes runtimne error in 32 bit. See the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515261/what-are-the-definitions-for-lparam-and-wparam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INT_PTR` and `LONG_PTR` are the same size as a pointer. So, they will be 32 bits wide in 32 bit targets, and 64 bits wide in 64 bit targets. It is simply wrong in C# to use either `int` or `long` since they have fixed sizes. The correct translation for both `INT_PTR` and `LONG_PTR` to C# is as `IntPtr`.

Similarly, for the unsigned variants, use `UIntPtr`.

Comment: Question...how do you map HALF_PTR (16bit on 32bit machines and 32bit on 64bit machines) in C#?

Comment: Does such a thing even exist?!

Comment: According to the Windows Data Types reference, yes. Though it does seem very strange to me - might not even be used anywhere

Comment: There's no C# type to match. I've never seen a use for such a type.